# How to get front and back camera preview in on layout by using custom camera in android

Tags: android-camera

how to preview the back camera and front camera in one activity (like half part front and half part back),but i search lot of links and websites till now i didn't get the solution could you please give that type of code or project please help me iam very critical situation ,Thanks in advance